# How to simulate Ubuntu ARM image on Raspberry Pi with Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, arm, vagrant, emulation

How do you run the [Ubuntu ARM image](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) in Virtualbox (ultimately managed through Vagrant) for testing a Raspberry Pi configuration?

I can find a ton of [guides](http://ediy.com.my/index.php/blog/item/52-virtualbox-raspberry-pi-emulator) for running various pre-built Raspberry Pi images in Virtualbox, but they all use Raspbian or Windows images and don't explain where those "ova" files came from, much less how they were created.